# Linux Mint: Can't install Archer T2UH usb wifi on kernel 4.8.0

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi

I bought a TP-link Archer T2UH wifi usb dongle. I am trying to install it on my work computer which has linux mint 18.2 Sofia with kernel 4.8.0.

I successfully installed it on my home comp, which has Mint 18 Sarah with kernel 4.4.0.21 using these instructions:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
make
sudo make install
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
sudo reboot
```

However, when trying the same on my work computer with the newer kernel, it gives an error when running "make":

```
/home/mikael/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49
: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function) struct 
ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
```

How to fix this?

Mikael